# Drawing in Java (beginner)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, turtle-graphics

I am new to Java and I am taking an online course. The course gave me this demo to try out, however, there are 4 errors that I do not know how to fix, and many of the other solutions on this website are not pertinent to what the class instructors want us to do. I have attached an image to show you the code. Screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YNS2.png). The errors say: cannot find symbol - class World; cannot find symbol - class Turtle.

Thank you!

Edit: I am trying to create a new World as an object and the same for Turtle

Comment: So, where are `World` and `Turtle`?

Comment: You are using World and Turtle as classes, so you have to create those classes before you use them.Post the complete code here.

Comment: You are creating new World as an object, that is right but objects are made after a class is defined. Have you created classes named World and Turtle??

Comment: In the demo code there is only 1 class which is the one shown in the screenshot. Perhaps I need to import one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the class names, and the method names shown, my belief is your code is supposed to use something like the [UCSD cseweb Turtle and World](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE11/turtleClassesDocs/turtleClasses/package-summary.html) classes, not reinvent them.  Were you supplied with library files to `import`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I found the answer - the book classes I had imported to the library had been deleted by accident. I re-downloaded them and now the classes are calling correctly.

Thanks again!